# How to know the direction of static friction with angular momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, friction, free-body-diagram

Why in the scenario of a rolling wheel is the static friction *against* the force when the rotation is clockwise? (The static friction is against it, usually.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the static friction is responsible for *generating* the circulation in the case of rolling without slipping. The reverse occurs when friction is a *resistance* to rolling.

This is similar to asking why a sliding mass decelerating under no other force has kinetic friction in the direction of its acceleration when "usually" (i.e. in the case when a force is pulling a sliding mass) the kinetic friction "is against it."

The direction of friction and the direction of circulation have no necessary relationship. Friction simply opposes the direction of *linear* motion (or potential linear motion, in the case of static friction). Rolling without slipping is the assertion that the bottom of the wheel is always stationary; friction is opposing the potential rightward sliding of the point at the bottom of the wheel along the ground.